# Proof that $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{i=0}{iP(X > i)} = \frac12(E(X²)-E(X))$ for $X$ nonnegative and integer valued

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

The following is a homework example:

For a nonnegative integer-valued random variable $X$, show that

$\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}{iP(X > i)} = 1/2(E(X²)-E(X)).$

The only way I could think of doing this proof is to rewrite the left side starting with:

$(1).$    $\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}{i} \sum^{\infty}_{j=i+1}{P(X=j}) = 1/2(E(X²)-E(X)).$

and continue from there to get to an expression similar to:

$(2).$    $1/2 * [\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}{i²*P(X=i)} - \sum^{\infty}_{i=0}{i*P(X=i))}] = 1/2(E(X²)-E(X)).$

However I don't know how to continue to transform $(1)$ into $(2)$. Could you give me a hint there? Is the approach even correct?

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196459/proving-the-following-equality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are on the right track.

When looking at the left side of equation $(1)$, note that for every value of $j$, you are multiplying $P(X=j)$ by every integer $i$ from $0$ through $j-1$. So for every $j$, you will have $(0+1+2+...+j-1)*P(X=j)$.

Since $(1+2+...+n)={n(n+1)\over 2}$, this becomes${j(j-1)\over 2}*P(X=j)=1/2*(j^2*P(X=j)-j*P(X=j)).$

Summing this up for every possible value for $j$ gives you the left side of equation $(2)$.

As far as the last step, there is a general formula for discrete random variables that $E[f(x)] =\sum^{n}_{i=1}{f(x_i)*P(X=x_i)}$ where $x_1,...,x_n$ are all of the possible values for $x$.

Since in your example $x$ can be any non-negative integer, you would get $E[X] = \sum^{\infty}_{i=0}{i*P(X=i)}$

$E[X^2]=\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}{i²*P(X=i)}$

and the rest of the equation follows easily.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The left part of equation (2) in my question was actually written by me and not given in the assignment. So I already know that this is the definition of the expectation value for nonnegative integers. However I have problems transforming equation $(1)$ in my question to equation $(2)$. I am a bit ashamed to have to admit that this might be the "follows easily" part. 
I just can't see from which formula the $1/2$, $i²$ and $minus$ in $(2)$ come from

Comment: I apologize, I misread and thought you were asking how to prove that equation $(2)$ is true.  I edited my answer to include how to get from $(1)$ to $(2)$, I hope it is clear enough.  And don't worry, that step was not what I was referring to in my last sentence.

Comment: Yes, it's a perfect explanation, thank you.