# Proving the following equality

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have to prove the following equality for a nonnegative integer-valued random variable X and I do not know where to start. I tried few times but everytime it makes no sense.

$\sum_{i=0}^\infty i \Bbb P  (X>i)= \frac 12 (\mathbf E(X^2) - \mathbf E(X))$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196142/proof-that-sum-limits-infty-i-0ipx-i-frac12ex%c2%b2-ex-for-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^\infty iP(X>i)
&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty i\sum_{j=i+1}^\infty P(X=j)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{i=0}^{j-1} i P(X=j)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(j-1)j}2P(X=j).
\end{align*}

Comment: Nope.  $\sum\limits_{i=1}^j i = \frac{j(j+1)}{2}$ but $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{j-1}i =\frac{(j-1)j}{2}$ as desired.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks for your remark.

Comment: How did the summations get swapped?

Comment: @Upstart We need to sum $iP(X=j)$ over certain values of $i$ and $j$. If $i=0$, then the possible values of $j$ are $1,2,3,\ldots$. This is the first sum. Alternatively, we can start with the value of $j$ and determine what the possible values of $i$ are. If $j=1$, then $i$ can only be equal to $0$, if $j=2$, then $i$ can be equal to $0$ and to $1$. This is how we obtain the second sum and this is how the summations get swapped. I hope this helps.